# XML Serialization over TCP Issues

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

Just testing a simple example program, for sending an XML Serialized object over TCP. I'm finding that unless I close the stream or `TcpClient` on the side that sends a serialized object, the receiver never receives it.

```
class Program
{
    private static XmlSerializer positionSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GazePosition));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(Server).Start();
        new Thread(Client).Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Server()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 30000);
        listener.Start();

        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var cmd = reader.ReadLine();
        if (cmd == "GetPosition")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received GetPosition Command");
            GazePosition pos = new GazePosition(-5, 5);
            positionSerializer.Serialize(stream, pos);
        }
        //client.Close();
        listener.Stop();
    }

    static void Client()
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 30000);
        Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine("GetPosition");
        writer.Flush();
        var pos = (GazePosition)positionSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", pos);
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("GazePosition")]
public class GazePosition
{
    [XmlElement("X")]
    public float X;
    [XmlElement("Y")]
    public float Y;

    public GazePosition()
    {

    }

    public GazePosition(float x, float y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", X, Y);
    }
}
```

This prints out only:

> Received GetPosition command

However, if I uncomment `client.Close()`

This prints out:

> Received GetPosition command
>
> Received -5, 5

I would like this example be able to scale to receiving multiple commands, but this is painful while I'm forced to close the stream each time I receive a command. If someone could enlighten me why this is happening,  I would be very thankful!

Comment: I have tested calling client.GetStream().Flush(), to no avail.

Comment: Ignoring the wrong usage of streams, you are reading a line, but you do not send a newline from client

Comment: My streamwriter in the client calls WriteLine

Comment: Kindly elaborate on 'wrong usage of stream's?

Comment: @Streams are `IDisposable`. I would properly dispose them :)

Comment: Thanks, I would usually but this  is just an example to demonstrate the TCP/XML :) I definitely could have used a 'using' clause

Answer (score 1):

Here what you are missing is that you are supposed to read from the TcpClient's stream on the client side. Please have a look what I simply did to get it to work. Please keep in mind that this is simply an example.

```
    writer.WriteLine("GetPosition");
    writer.Flush();

    //Just like you did you should seperate the payload
    //Either by size or new line or some special key you set
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        var gazePos = (GazePosition)positionSerializer.Deserialize(ms);
        //DOSTUFF
    }
    //Added code finished
```

Here is some simple `beta` level library. You may want to have a look→
[Simple Server](https://github.com/emrahsungu/Hes.Socket.Server/blob/master/Hes.Socket/Listeners/TcpSocket.cs)

Edit: I further looked at `NetworkStream`'s `Dispose` method. It has native calls to Windows API so I am not able to further into implementation details.However, as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/graceful-shutdown-linger-options-and-socket-closure-2), during a graceful shutdown, which occurs when you dispose a network stream, sends a `FD_CLOSE`

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Is there a reason I cant de-serialize directly from the TCP Stream? This doesn't really answer why closing the stream on the server side fixes the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the specific implementaion of `XmlSerializer` as to why you can not deserialize directly from `Stream. However, from your comments it looks like you can deserialize from `Stream` if you close the stream. So if I should make a guess, it requires end of stream, don't you think so?

Comment: @Naxin, I replaced your client.Close() with stream.Dispose() and successfully received a response. I think, more or less I can say that XmlSerializer while desrializing reads until the end of stream.